# Parsing Nested JSON in java without know structure of JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, jettison

I have a use case where i get a random jsonstring and variable name. I need to verify if that particular variable is present in that json, and if present fetch its value. For example, let us the json is as follows

```
{
   "a" : {
        "b":1,
        "c":2
   }
}
```

Along with above jsonString, say i get an input "a.b" . Now I need to return 1.
Is there any library to achieve this in java directly?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html

Comment: Is the structure going to be the same as above? I mean are just the keys going to be random or even the structure can be random?

Comment: Even the structure can be random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) is a library that provides the functionality you're after.

You will have to do some conversion between your input and the library's input.

As per your example, if your input is "a.b":

```
String convertedInput = ".." + input
JsonPath.read(json, convertedInput)
```